# How to remove words (count limited) of a string in PHP

Tags: php, string

Q: How to remove words (count limited to 3 chars) of a string in PHP

Example String: "Remove all words of 3 letters"
Expected String: "Remove words letters"

Basically, remove all words that are less than equal to 3 counts.

Thanks.

Comment: *Words* seems to be a loose term considering you also removed the *3*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the word boundry:

```
preg_replace('/\b(?:^|\s\w{1,3})\b/', '', $sentance);
```

Jack's answer only matched all and of.

This expression looks for the word boundaries and will match on that.

Comment: My answer also matches '3' :)

Answer (score 3):

Regular expression to select words between 1 and 3 in length:

```
preg_replace('/\b\w{1,3}\b\s*/', '', $sentence);
```

The `\b` is to match a word boundary, the `\w` denotes a "word" character. The `\s*` at the end makes sure that excess spaces are removed too.